# css dropdown list not working in FF 20.0.1

Tags: css

I am using css to create a dropdown menu. This works perfectly in google chrome V26, IE9, Safari v 5.1.7, but it does not work at all in FF v20.0.1. i'm wondering if anyone has any hints or tips for me. To me, its basic css, so it should work fine in FF. Any ideas or helpful hints would be appreciated. Thanks you.

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 49px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #141414;
      background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a),     color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #141414;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALElEQVQImWMwMrJi+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZoPR/qBgDEhuXGLoeYswhXg8R5gAAdVpfoJ3dB5oAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #32323a),     color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #32323a 0%, #141414 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 49px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c),     color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background: #070707;
  background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAxCAIAAACUDVRzAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAALklEQVQImWNQU9Nh+v//PxMDw3+m//8ZkNj/mRgYIHxy5f//Z0BSi18e2TwS5QG4MGB54HL+mAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==) 100% 100%; 
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #26262c),     color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #26262c 0%, #070707 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul a {
  color: #333;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #f7f7f7;
  filter: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #d8d8d8;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #d8d8d8;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #e7e7e7;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #bebebe;
}
```

And here is the html

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
  <li class='active'><a href='index.php'><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li class='has-sub'><a href='services.php'><span>Services</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='employee-benefits.php'><span>Employee Benefits</span></a></li>
  <li><a href='associate-benefits.php'><span>Associate Benefits</span></a></li>
  <li class='last'><a href='safety-training.php'><span>Safety Training</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='has-sub'><a href='about.php'><span>About</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='who-we-are-and-what-we-do.php'><span>Who We Are and What We Do</span></a></li>
  <li><a href='presidents-statement.php'><span>Presidents Statement</span></a></li>
  <li class='last'><a href='vice-presidents-statement.php'><span>Vice Presidents Statement</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='career-opportunities.php'><span>Career Opportunities</span></a></li>
  <li><a href='projects.php'><span>Projects</span></a></li>
  <li><a href='links.php'><span>Links</span></a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class='last'><a href='contact.php'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you also posted your HTML code - please create a Jsfiddle as well (http://jsfiddle.net/) and link it in your question

Comment: Copied to http://jsfiddle.net/d4VxB/

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code into JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/bG2MK/) and tried it in FF 19 before upgrading to FF 20.0.1 and the drop-down boxes are working in terms of them dropping down.  What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: It would be helpful to describe what is happening and what you would expect to happen.

Comment: FF20.0.1 works dropddown menu

Comment: When i hover over each menu item using FF 21.0, the menu does not pull down for services and about. could it be a setting in my FF version which is preventing it? when you hover over the services menu and the about menu, each should have a list of three items displays under the menu